# Regex validate only the result of a captured group

Tags: regex

I have this regex to detect an email address:

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]{8,})@(\S+\.\S+)
```

The requirement: The part before `@` needs to contain at least one letter and be at least 8 characters long.

I'm using positive lookahead to see if it contains a letter, but lookahead actually apply to the entire line (the part after `@` usually will contain letters), so this will pass

`123456789@gmail.com`

So question is, how can I validate only the result of the first capturing group (in this case `123456789`) to see if it has a letter or not?

Comment: Replace `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` with `(?=[^@]*[a-zA-Z])`

Comment: You might also add not matching a char a-zA-Z in the negated character class `(?=[^@\na-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])`  https://regex101.com/r/D9efB9/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
thank you, why didn't I think of it. Please make an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]{8,}` consuming pattern part before `@` does not match `@`, so the lookahead check should only check for a letter after 0 or more chars *other than* `@`.

Using

```
(?=[^@]*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]{8,})@(\S+\.\S+)
```

will fix the issue. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KsEi68/1) and a [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3D%5B%5E%40%5D*%5Ba-zA-Z%5D)(%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_.%2B-%5D%7B8%2C%7D)%40(%5CS%2B%5C.%5CS%2B)):

[image]

You may further optimize the lookahead pattern by precising the `[^@]`. E.g. since you only allow `0-9_.+-` apart from letters, you may write the regex as

```
(?=[0-9_.+-]*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]{8,})@(\S+\.\S+)
    ^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KsEi68/2).

Or, you may follow the [principle of contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) ([suggested in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55740532/regex-validate-only-the-result-of-a-captured-group/55740754#comment98158470_55740532)), and use `[^@a-zA-Z]*` instead of `[^@]*`.

Depending on where you are using the regex, you might want to wrap it with `^` and `$` anchors to ensure a full string match.